# How do I change a property of a DOM node that doesn't require a re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I may well be going about this the wrong way, but here goes. I'm trying to "reactify" Google's Autocomplete field. That is not itself important to know, but gives you the background that led me to this question.

I'm using the HTML5 Geolocation API to set the bias bounds for the autocomplete results. This is done asynchronously. When/How should I update the component?

Is react smart enough to only re-render if a property is bound to a state value?

The parent is doing the geolocation. Is this safe in the constructor?

Comment: The question might as well also be asked as a "when do I do this" as well.

Comment: What DOM node property are you trying to update?

Comment: It's the "bounds" property of the autocomplete input class. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete

Comment: Presumably, you have a reference to the `Autocomplete` you've created - you can just call `setBounds` on it after you receive a result from geolocation (you'll have to convert the result to what it expects, and determine a bounds somehow). React won't re-render anything if you don't explicitly set the state.

Comment: The geolocation is handled in the parent. My issue is how do I let the child know about it?